# How to get the key and print it inside an HTML tag?

Tags: php, html

I am new in PHP and I my problem is I want to pass the keys/value in my table. Is there any other way to tdo this? Thank you!

Here are my codes:

```
<?php
$array = array(
"Salary of Mr. A is " => "1000$",
"Salary of Mr. B is " => "1200$",
"Salary of Mr. C is " => "1400$");              
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><?= $array[0]; ?></td>
        <td><?= $array["Salary of Mr. A is "]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?= $array["Salary of Mr. B is "]; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?= $array["Salary of Mr. C is "]; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is

```
    <?php
        $array = array(
        "Salary of Mr. A is " => "1000$",
        "Salary of Mr. B is " => "1200$",
        "Salary of Mr. C is " => "1400$");              
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
    <?php foreach ($array as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use foreach loop, save your works and times.

```
<?php
$array = array(
"Salary of Mr. A is " => "1000$",
"Salary of Mr. B is " => "1200$",
"Salary of Mr. C is " => "1400$");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<?php

foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $key . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

?>
</table>
</body>
 </html>
```